# How to remove hyperlink from: a href

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

How can I remove/prevent a link from being linked to go for a page?

I want it to still be clickable but instead going to a page, just do nothing, stay on the same page.

For example, I have this:

```
<a href="nothing">Hyperlink</a>
```

How can I disable the link of it? Presumably I have to write something else than `"nothing"`?

Comment: You open an editor and remove the markup around "Hyperlink"?

Comment: no like, I want it to still be clickable but insted going to page just do nothing just stay on the same page

Comment: You can use '#' instead of 'nothing', and the link wont redirect you to anything. If thats what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

use

`<a href="javascript:void(0);">link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<a href"#" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">Hyperlink</a>
```

The `return false` will prevent the href to go anywhere.

or simply

```
<a href='#'>Hyperlink</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

# doesn't redirect but show  cursor pointer.

```
<a href="#" class="demo">something</a>
```

if you want to change the cursor property.
add the css

```
.demo{
   cursor:default;
  }
```